# Level List Not working for ImageView - Android

Tags: android, drawable

I was practicing level list in android and created a small app, but when i try to change the levels, the image in the image view is not changing...

By default it's showing first image in `level_list.xml`

activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/level_list" />
```

level_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/logo"/>
        <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ruppe_btn1_selected"/>
    </level-list>
```

MainActivity.Kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val imageLevelList = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageButton)
        imageLevelList.setImageLevel(0) //tried with 1
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to change `android:maxLevel` order in `level_list.xml` file

Just change the order like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ruppe_btn1_selected"/>
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/logo"/>
</level-list>
```